# Editing already printed text in python

Tags: python

I want to edit an already printed text but not clear the text before it, and clearing the whole cmd and printing it again + the text I want to print won't achieve my goal.

Comment: Please read "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)," and add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that does what you want.

```
import time
i = 0
while True:
    var = "Half-seconds passed {}".format(i)
    print(var, end="\r")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    i += 1
```